# Codeigniter query builder using implode function in where_in

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, implode, where-in

Here is my normal sql query using implode function:

```
SELECT * from search_result WHERE skills IN ('".implode("','",$s_id)."');
```

Now I want to convert this to codeigniter form. I tried the following code but it fails

```
$this->db->from('search_result');
$this->db->where_in('skills','".implode("','",$s_id)."');
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Here is my `$s_id` array:

```
Array ( [0] => 2D Design [1] => 3D Design [2] => 3D Modelling )
```

So anyone please help me to do this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: pass `$s_id` as array

Comment: @AbdullaNilam can you show an example please..

Comment: add `$s_id` values

Comment: @AbdullaNilam please check my update

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Official Doc say's**

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James'); # Data Array 
$this->db->where_in('username', $names); # passing array
```

---

Try  like below

**Method 01**(*recommended* )

```
$this->db->from('search_result');
$this->db->where_in('skills',$s_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

**Method 02**

```
$this->db->from('search_result');
$this->db->where_in('skills',implode("','",$s_id));
$query = $this->db->get();
```

---

**Whats wrong on this line**

```
$this->db->where_in('skills','".implode("','",$s_id)."');
```

don't wrap function with `'` or `"` quotes. Then it will get save as STRING value to DB.

---

**Links**

1. [`where_in` clause in codeigniter.com](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where_in)

Answer (score 1):

You can just write this :

```
$this->db->from('search_result');
$this->db->where_in('skills', $s_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

[Official doc](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where_in)

> $names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
>
> $this->db->where_in('username', $names);
>
> // Produces: WHERE username IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')